# how can I determine the maximum value of 'backlog' that is allowed on the current system?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm playing with ServerSocket and I don't see / find what the **limit** of the **backlog** is. The docs don't say anything about this:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int, int)

My code is like this:

```
serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocket.socket().bind(null, 10000);
```

but I assume that 10000 might be too much if a system doesn't have enough RAM. So is there a way to determine the maximum value for **backlog** that I can use?

It seems like in c++ you can use SOMAXCONN - does something similar exist for Java?

Comment: If you are using anything like the default limit of 50, you have a serious problem.  Can you think of a good reason to increase it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there were, it would be system dependent: for [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms739168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The backlog parameter is limited
>   (silently) to a reasonable value as
>   determined by the underlying service
>   provider. Illegal values are replaced
>   by the nearest legal value. There is
>   no standard provision to find out the
>   actual backlog value.

[Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) states it a little differently but you would need to go through the sysctl interface (or possibly /proc).

In any case, it would appear you would need to execute some system specific code.

I believe most implementations will just use their maximum value if the specified value is "too big" so this may not be a concern for your application?